# Imported but unused in python

Tags: python, pyspider

```
import bumpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as per
import pandas as pd.
```

Console showing some warning. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: Please add more detail to the question

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: If console shows some warning, you need to fix something.

Comment: @bereal Well you don't _need_ to, but probably _should_... Warnings aren't errors :)

Comment: This is not a big deal. If you want this warning to go away, just don't import any module you aren't actually using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, when you import a library, it is expected to be utilized in the code blocks. Hence, as it obviously states, you may have imported these but have not used all of them.

Besides that being the obvious warning, your imports should have been

```
import numpy as np
```

***NOT*** `bumpy`.

And remove the unnecessary period following the pandas import.

```
import pandas as pd
```

But **if you still want to have imports and not use them**, or keep them for later declarations, you could choose to suppress or ignore the warnings, *which I do not endorse*. But, if you so badly want to get rid of 'em, you can do so by adding the following line to the beginning of your code.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Comment: yes numpy, its my mystake while posting.

Comment: I need to just import those packages.can u please help me on that.

Comment: So, there's no issue. You can simply add the ***ignore warnings*** statement as I've indicated my response and import these libraries. Then, you shouldn't be getting any warnings.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably from e.g. [pyflakes](https://pypi.org/project/pyflakes/) shown in your [IDE](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments) console.

It just gives you a hint that you've imported a module and not used it (yet).

The warning will go away as soon as you've used at least one function from the imported modules in the following code.